# Ограничение позиции тела

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как ограничить позицию тела если оно движется с помощью силы, Clamp не подходит тело начинает дрожать?

Rigidbody velocity показывает 0

Comment: ? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Constraints.html

Comment: @AntonNikolaev, мне нужно чтобы тело двигалось по x, в заданном промежутке от -5 до 5